# Grok Filter Error in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I have the following in my filter, for some reason it only prints email and not delivery_status. But when I comment out the email it then prints the delivery _status.

Is there a way to print them both without commenting either of them out?

```
filter {   
    grok {
      patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns/postfix"]
      match => { "message" => "%{EMAIL}" }
      match => { "message" => "%{DELIVERY_STATUS}" }
      overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }     

}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `grok` filter finishes on the first successful match. If you want to overwrite this behaviour, add this line:

```
break_on_match => false
```

For further reference check out the grok filter docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).

Comment: Thanks, my solution was to add multiple grok filters. But your suggestion is equally a neat solution. Thanks.